# Swift 3 - setting a UITextField for currency in Euro

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, uitextfield, currency

I have a UIViewController with various UITextFields and UIImageViews. I want one of the text fields to be set for currency so that the user can insert how much money he wants to spend and the numbers are nicely inserted with the correct decimal point and if needed the numbers can also be deleted. I have tried to follow some of the answers on StackOverflow but every one uses a textField function which changes every textfield on the page and not only the one I want. I would also like to set a maximum amount of money (for example 10000 Euro). I am new to coding in Swift and I cannot figure it out.